# 500 Internal Server Error- dojo.js or my php file?

Tags: php, dojo, pdo

I have sort of problem. It is `500 Internal Server Error`.

This happened  during my development. 
I could not figure what caused the problem.
I am using dojo, php and pdo. Please see the red circles as indicated in the pictures below. These circles indicate my php file, dojo.js and selected item indicated.
It happened when I selected one of the items in the dojo comboBox.

Can you point me to the root of the problem?

[image: 500 Internal Server Error - Headers]
[image: 500 Internal Server Error - Post]

Comment: check your http error logs

Comment: I forgot to add Also I selected the item, the alert error pops up "Batch's error: RequestError: Unable to load gatherbatches.php status 500"

Comment: yeah, status 500 means the file is giving you an error. you have an error in your php file. check your log.

Comment: JS Cannot generate a "server error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test_MkTests.php page and its javascript loads fine.
Then javascript calls gatherbaches.php but http server gives 500 internal server error.
Check your gatherbaches.php, php_error.log and  http server error log. Check your FirePHP.class.php ( 612 line )

Try load gatherbaches.php directly in browser to check it is working.

Comment: Ok I tested each php file separately and each is working fine. When put them together,  only one of them in the first order is working. So if two are swapped in the order, the first order is working.  These files are gathertests2.php and gatherbatches.php. It does not matter which is working, because the first order is always working and the second order is not. And the error says "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function alert()" in either of both.

Comment: And the script is followed as "$result = $stmt_call1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $output = json_encode($result); echo $output;" This script is applied to both  files. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: try() catch
{
 alert($err->getMessage((PDOException $err)));  
}

Comment: You can not use alert() inside php to pop up from the browser when the server reaches a certain point in your php code. Use print() or echo or depend on your needs change your logic. Anyway do not use alert().

Comment: I put this alert script in this catch exception and it used after the PDO's execution of mysql syntax.

Comment: Oh... I overlook this. Thanks

Comment: There is NO alert() function in PHP. Why do you think PHP terminates with: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function alert()" ?